# Timestamp validation with regex. jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-ui, timestamp

My goal is to validate timestamps(format: `mm/dd/yy h:mmt` e.g. `04/25/2014 11:39a`) with Javascript and jQuery UI using a regex statement:

`/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d[ ]([1-9]|1[0-2])[:]([0-5][0-9])(a|p)$/`

My regex statement works with the formatted timestamps on these two sites:

1. [Rubular](http://rubular.com)
2. [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)

However, when I use the `valid` option with a regexMatch in widget factory it doesn't recognize the timestamp as a valid value.

This is my object literal for my widget:

```
widgetName: 'field',
  widgetOptions: {
    label:    'From',
    code:     'fromFilterValue',
    width: 160,
    required:  true,
    valid: { 
      regexpMatch: [
                    '/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d[ ]([1-9]|1[0-2])[:]([0-5][0-9])(a|p)$/',
                    { field: '_newValue' }
                  ]
                }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My widget was complaining about the `\d` syntax for all digits.  I replaced all `\d` with `[0-9]` and it worked fine.

Can anyone explain why `\d` doesn't work?